# How do you make an HTML document writable in the browser?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, edit-in-place

Lest my question is not clear; I don't mean dynamically replacing `<p>` nodes with `<textarea>`. I mean editing each and all text directly - including headers, text in `<div>` and `<span>` and yes editing tables. I know this is possible in IE and I have a script which switches between editable and back which works in IE, but that doesn't work in Firefox. Is there any way to make it work in FF?

P.S. The script for IE I got from [JavaScript Bible Gold Edition by Danny Goodman, 2001](http://books.google.com/books?id=9e2jQgAACAAJ&dq=JavaScript%20Bible%20Gold%20Edition%20by%20Danny%20Goodman,&source=gbs_book_other_versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firefox > 3 you can use *contentEditable* for html elements I understood. A tag looks like this:

```
<div id="myEditableDiv" contentEditable="true">click here to edit ...</div>
```

you can control the editing process with 'execCommand' (see: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(VS.85).aspx) for command identifiers)

Answer (score 4):

[Firebug Extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox pretty much allows you to edit anything.